# Converting python.io object to std::istream when using boost::python

Tags: python, c++, io, boost-python

While writing my first django application I've faced the following problem with *boost::python*. From python code, I need to pass [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams) to the C++ class which takes *std::istream*.

I have a legacy C++ library for reading files of certain format. Let's call is *somelib*. The interface of this library uses *std::istream* as an input. Something like this:

```
class SomeReader
{
public:
    bool read_from_stream(std::istream&);
};
```

And I want to wrap it, so that I can use my lib from python in the following way:

```
reader = somelib.SomeReader()
print ">>Pyhton: reading from BytesIO"
buf = io.BytesIO("Hello Stack Overflow")
reader.read(buf)
```

I found out how to do it for actual python file object. But it is not clear how to do it for arbitrary **file-like** object. This is definition of the python bindings I have so far:

```
using namespace boost::python;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

struct SomeReaderWrap: SomeReader, wrapper<SomeReader>
{
    bool read(object &py_file)
    {
        if (PyFile_Check(py_file.ptr()))
        {
            FILE* handle = PyFile_AsFile(py_file.ptr());
            io::stream_buffer<io::file_descriptor_source> fpstream (fileno(handle), io::never_close_handle);
            std::istream in(&fpstream);
            return this->read_from_stream(in);
        }
        else
        {
            //
            // How do we implement this???
            //
            throw std::runtime_error("Not a file, have no idea how to read this!");
        }
    }
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(somelib)
{
    class_<SomeReaderWrap, boost::noncopyable>("SomeReader")
        .def("read", &SomeReaderWrap::read);
}
```

Is there a more or less generic way of converting python IO object to the C++ stream?

Thank you in advance.

---

As a result of my experiments I've created a small [github repo](https://github.com/peter-popov/python_io_to_cpp_stream) which illustrates this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of converting the Python [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams) object, consider implementing a model of the Boost.IOStreams [Source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/source.html) concept that is capable of reading from a Python `io.BytesIO` object.  This would allow one to construct a [`boost::iostreams::stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream) and be useable by `SomeReader::read_from_stream()`.

This [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/container_source.html) demonstrates how to create and use a custom Boost.IOStream Source.  Overall, the process should be fairly straight forward.  One just needs to implement the Source concept's `read()` function in terms of [`io.BufferedIOBase.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read):

```cpp
/// Type that implements the Boost.IOStream's Source concept for reading
/// data from a Python object supporting read(size).
class PythonInputDevice
  : public boost::iostreams::source // Use convenience class.
{
public:

  explicit
  PythonInputDevice(boost::python::object object)
    : object_(object)
  {}

  std::streamsize read(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize buffer_size) 
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    // Read data through the Python object's API.  The following is
    // is equivalent to:
    //   data = object_.read(buffer_size)
    boost::python::object py_data = object_.attr("read")(buffer_size);
    std::string data = python::extract<std::string>(py_data);

    // If the string is empty, then EOF has been reached.
    if (data.empty())
    {
      return -1; // Indicate end-of-sequence, per Source concept.
    }

    // Otherwise, copy data into the buffer.
    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), buffer);
    return data.size();
  }

private:
  boost::python::object object_;
};
```

then create a `boost::iostreams::stream` using the Source device:

```cpp
boost::iostreams::stream<PythonInputDevice> input(py_object);
SomeReader reader;
reader.read_from_stream(input);
```

As `PythonInputDevice` is implemented in terms of `object.read()`, [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) allows `PythonInputDevice` to be used with any Python object supporting a `read()` method that has the same pre and post-conditions.  This include's the built-in Python [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) object, making it no longer necessary to have conditional branching based on type within `SomeReaderWrap::read()`.

---

Here is a complete minimal example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iosfwd> // std::streamsize
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/concepts.hpp>  // boost::iostreams::source
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

class SomeReader
{
public:
  bool read_from_stream(std::istream& input)
  {
    std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input.rdbuf()),
                        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    std::cout << "SomeReader::read_from_stream(): " << content << std::endl;
    return true;      
  }
};

/// Type that implements a model of the Boost.IOStream's Source concept
/// for reading data from a Python object supporting:
///   data = object.read(size).
class PythonInputDevice
  : public boost::iostreams::source // Use convenience class.
{
public:

  explicit
  PythonInputDevice(boost::python::object object)
    : object_(object)
  {}

  std::streamsize read(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize buffer_size) 
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    // Read data through the Python object's API.  The following is
    // is equivalent to:
    //   data = object_.read(buffer_size)
    boost::python::object py_data = object_.attr("read")(buffer_size);
    std::string data = python::extract<std::string>(py_data);

    // If the string is empty, then EOF has been reached.
    if (data.empty())
    {
      return -1; // Indicate end-of-sequence, per Source concept.
    }

    // Otherwise, copy data into the buffer.
    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), buffer);
    return data.size();
  }

private:
  boost::python::object object_;
};

struct SomeReaderWrap
  : SomeReader,
    boost::python::wrapper<SomeReader>
{
  bool read(boost::python::object& object)
  {
    boost::iostreams::stream<PythonInputDevice> input(object);
    return this->read_from_stream(input);
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<SomeReaderWrap, boost::noncopyable>("SomeReader")
    .def("read", &SomeReaderWrap::read)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
$ echo -n "test file" > test_file
$ python
>>> import example
>>> with open('test_file') as f:
...     reader = example.SomeReader()
...     reader.read(f)
... 
SomeReader::read_from_stream(): test file
True
>>> import io
>>> with io.BytesIO("Hello Stack Overflow") as f:
...     reaader = example.SomeReader()
...     reader.read(f)
... 
SomeReader::read_from_stream(): Hello Stack Overflow
True
```